# Aspect capturing additional Pointcuts

Tags: java, spring-boot, aop, spring-aop, aspect

I've been getting these messages at startup of my Spring Boot service.

```
Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final void org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(javax.servlet.ServletRequest,javax.servlet.ServletResponse,javax.servlet.FilterChain) throws javax.servlet.ServletException,java.io.IOException] because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!

Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final void org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean.init(javax.servlet.FilterConfig) throws javax.servlet.ServletException] because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!
```

The problem's I can't figure out what classes are getting selected by my Pointcut that is causing this:

My Aspect file:

```
@Around("execution(public * com.torchai..*.*(..)) "
        + "&& loggingEnabledAndNotDisabled()"
        + "&& !allPublicControllerMethodsNotDisabled()"
        + "&& !allPublicControllerLayerMethodsNotDisabled()"
        + "&& !allPublicServiceMethodsNotDisabled()"
        + "&& !allPublicServiceLayerMethodsNotDisabled()")
public Object allPublicMethodsNotDisabledAndNotControllerOrService(
              final ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
    return log(proceedingJoinPoint, LogEvent.LAYER_OTHER);
}

@AfterThrowing(
        pointcut = "execution(public * com.torchai..*.*(..)) "
                + "&& loggingEnabledAndNotDisabled()"
                + "&& !allPublicControllerMethodsNotDisabled()"
                + "&& !allPublicControllerLayerMethodsNotDisabled()"
                + "&& !allPublicServiceMethodsNotDisabled()"
                + "&& !allPublicServiceLayerMethodsNotDisabled()",
        throwing = "t")
public void allPublicMethodsNotDisabledAndNotControllerOrService(
            final JoinPoint joinPoint, final Throwable t) {
    onException(joinPoint, t, LogEvent.LAYER_OTHER);
}
```

I'm not pasting in all the supporting Pointcuts, but you can see they are the same for `@Around` and `@AfterThrowing`. These points cuts should not be selecting anything at this point.

What I find really interesting is if I totally comment out the `@Around` code, the problem is still there.

But if I leave the `@Around` code and comment out `@AfterThrowing`, the problem is gone.

So even though these 2 things should be equivalent in terms of what they select, for some reason `@AfterThrowing` is selecting something that is causing the problem.

### Update

@kriegaex Thanks for your through response.  Here are my other pointcuts.  Was just trying to keep things simple by not including them.

```
    @Pointcut("@annotation(com.torchai.service.aspect.annotations.AspectLog) "
            + "|| @target(com.torchai.service.aspect.annotations.AspectLog)")
    public void methodOrClassLoggingEnabled() {
    }

    @Pointcut("!@annotation(com.torchai.service.aspect.annotations.AspectNoLog)")
    public void methodLoggingNotDisabled() {
    }

    @Pointcut("methodOrClassLoggingEnabled() && methodLoggingNotDisabled()")
    public void loggingEnabledAndNotDisabled() {
    }

    /**
     * Any public methods in classes which are specifically annotated as a Controller
     */
    @Pointcut("within(@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController *) ||"
            + "within(@org.springframework.stereotype.Controller *)")
    public void allPublicControllerMethods() {
    }

    /**
     * Any public methods in classes which are specifically annotated as a Service
     */
    @Pointcut("within(@org.springframework.stereotype.Service *)")
    public void allPublicServiceMethods() {
    }

    // Controller classes are enabled by default, so don't need to be specifically enabled.
    @Pointcut("allPublicControllerMethods() "
            + "&& methodLoggingNotDisabled()")
    public void allPublicControllerMethodsNotDisabled() {
    }

    // Service classes are enabled by default, so don't need to be specifically enabled.
    @Pointcut("allPublicServiceMethods() "
            + "&& methodLoggingNotDisabled()")
    public void allPublicServiceMethodsNotDisabled() {
    }

    // Components which aren't Service classes, but in the service package need to be enabled with @AspectLog
    @Pointcut("execution(public * com.torchai.service..service..*(..)) "
            + "&& loggingEnabledAndNotDisabled()")
    public void allPublicServiceLayerMethodsNotDisabled() {
    }

    // Components which aren't Controller classes, but in the controller package need to be enabled with @AspectLog
    @Pointcut("execution(public * com.torchai.service..controller..*(..)) "
            + "&& loggingEnabledAndNotDisabled()")
    public void allPublicControllerLayerMethodsNotDisabled() {
    }

    @Around("allPublicControllerMethodsNotDisabled() "
            + "|| allPublicControllerLayerMethodsNotDisabled()")
    public Object logController(final ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
        return log(proceedingJoinPoint, LogEvent.LAYER_CONTROLLER);
    }

    @Around("allPublicServiceMethodsNotDisabled() "
            + "|| allPublicServiceLayerMethodsNotDisabled()")
    public Object logService(final ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
        return log(proceedingJoinPoint, LogEvent.LAYER_SERVICE);
    }
```

I understand the basic meaning of the message, although admittedly, I'm not sure how to do the JDK proxy instead.  But I don't think it really necessary.  We do have a Filter class which implements `OncePerRequestFilter`, but I can't be sure that that is the one getting picked up, because it doesn't say.

But my real confusion is not just that a class is getting picked up that I didn't expect, but that it seems to only get picked up by the `@AfterThrowing` and not by `@Around` .  Why wouldn't these be exactly the same?

### Update #2 (a few minutes later)

I'm thinking this might have something to do with my used of `execution` as opposed to your suggestion of `within`.  I don't fully understand the difference.  But still, the definitions in `@AfterThrowing` and `@Around` are the same.  And even where I'm using `execution`, it still needs to match the other conditions.

### Update #3

I've created a repo that shows the problem: https://github.com/peterkronenberg/aoptest

At startup, Springboot issues these messages:

```
2022-03-24 15:58:57.261  INFO 35104 --- [           main] o.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy          : Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final void org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(javax.servlet.ServletRequest,javax.servlet.ServletResponse,javax.servlet.FilterChain) throws javax.servlet.ServletException,java.io.IOException] because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!
2022-03-24 15:58:57.261  INFO 35104 --- [           main] o.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy          : Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final void org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean.init(javax.servlet.FilterConfig) throws javax.servlet.ServletException] because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!
2022-03-24 15:58:57.310 ERROR 35104 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Exception starting filter [authFilter]
```

The service doesn't start up, which is not what I was seeing originally.  But maybe that provides more clues.  But if I disabled the Aspect code, simply by commenting out the `@Aspect` annotation in the `AspectLayer` class, then it seems to work.
Somehow, there is a conflict between my Aspect code and my Filter code

I do *not* want my AuthFilter class to be picked up by my Aspect code.  I believe that's what is causing the problem, although I'm not sure why

Comment: I think I can explain to you what is going on. But before I do, please give me some more context. Why are those two messages bothering you? They should be logged on INFO. Is there any follow-up problem when starting or using the application? Because this is what I am seeing when trying to reproduce those log messages.

Comment: I understand they are not hurting anything, but it's also telling me that there is a Pointcut where I don't expect one.  There is no reason that any of the filters should be getting called.  So I'm just trying to understand what's going on

Comment: To @ℛɑƒæĿᴿᴹᴿ who reformatted the original code block to a normal text quote: Log output should be in a code block, even if it means horizontal scrolling. I reverted that.

Answer (score 1):

Let us inspect the error message with some extra line breaks:

```
Unable to proxy interface-implementing method
  public final void org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(
    javax.servlet.ServletRequest,
    javax.servlet.ServletResponse,
    javax.servlet.FilterChain
  )
  throws javax.servlet.ServletException,java.io.IOException

because it is marked as final:
  Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!
```

What that means is that

- somewhere in your application (or in a dependency) you have a `Filter` class extending `OncePerRequestFilter` and
- somehow Spring AOP is trying to proxy it.
- The way it is trying to proxy it is by using CGLIB proxies.
- CGLIB proxies work by creating subclasses and overriding methods so as to be able to intercept them and delegate to the original ones or skip them, whatever the developer prefers.
- Spring framework class `OncePerRequestFilter` implements an interface method `doFilter` from `Filter`, but for some reason declares it `final`. I.e., when proxying the filter, the final method from the parent class cannot be proxied. If later you call it on the proxy instance, it actually ends up in the original object. You cannot hook into it with aspects, advisors or method interceptors.
- The hint "consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead" means that if you need to hook into such a method, you could configure Spring to create a JDK proxy instead of a CGLIB proxy. That way, the proxy would directly implement methods of all interfaces the target class implements, and you could hook into those two final methods. But in that case, other target class methods which do not implement any interface methods cannot be intercepted anymore. It is a trade-off, choose whichever variant is better for you, because you cannot have both.

Now with regard to your astonishment that some classes are being targeted at all by Spring AOP, you need to understand that many pointcuts are being evaluated dynamically, especially if they contain things like `this()`, `target()`, `@(target)` etc. which need runtime information. Users are often surprised that their generic pointcuts seem to "proxy the world", often even  including Spring's own framework beans. Usually, you can limit that by scoping the pointcuts with something like `&& within(org.acme.myapp..**)`. You can try that. Not being able to see your many pointcuts, I can only speculate what they might contain, but like so often in software development the devil is in the details.

---

**Update after question edit:** Like I speculated before, you are using dynamic pointcuts such as `@target` and `@annotation` and a bunch of `within(@org.springframework..* *)` stuff which also targets Spring's own beans. But what I am missing is some application-specific package scoping `&& within(org.acme.myapp..**)`, like I suggested before. So all of what I said before still holds. Neither have you reported back on whether you tried that and what the effect was, nor have you said if you found the bean(s) extending `OncePerRequestFilter` and `GenericFilterBean`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response.  I edit the question to add some more information

Comment: please see my updates in the original question. I'd appreciate it if you can give me some more insight

Comment: Sorry, I was quite busy. I have updated my answer, but you did not say if you tried any of the thing I suggested previously.

Comment: I did say that I have a file that extends `OncePerFilter`, but it's impossible to tell if that's the file that is getting called because the message doesn't call out the classname.    I'm still trying to understand why `@AfterThrowing` is behaving different from `@Around`, even though the definitions are the same.   I guess I did not quite understand what you meant by dynamic pointcuts.  Should I be using `@within(com.torchai..**)` instead of `execution(public * com.torchai..*.*(..))` ?

Comment: In previous comment, I meant `within` and not `@within`

Comment: So did you try limiting the scope using `within` instead of `execution`? Does it help to avoid proxying the `OncePerFilter` subclass? I did not get a reproducer project from you, so I cannot test it myself, only produce a similar situation locally. If you want to be sure which class Spring tries to proxy, simply set a breakpoint in `CglibAopProxy` and start the application in debug mode. Then drill down into `this` → `targetSource` → `target` as shown [in this screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/fKSouka.png), then see for yourself.

Comment: It does not make a difference, hence me trying to understand what the difference is supposed to be.  My `OncePerFilter` class is still in my app package, so I wouldn't really expect it to be eliminated.  I still don't understand why it's getting picked up at all, since it doesn't satisfy the conditions that I'm specifying in the code I posted.  And I still don't understand why leaving the `@AfterThrowing` uncommented is what caused the problem, even though no exceptions are being thrown.  But leaving `@Around` uncommented does not cause a problem at all

Comment: Look, this is not a discussion forum but a Q/A platform. Why don't you just provide the MCVE I requested? I can only speculate that your filter class is inside the `com.torchai` package and therefore included in AOP proxying. In that case, simply exclude the subpackage or the class, e.g. `!within(com.torchai.filters..*)` or `!within(com.torchai.x.y.MyFilter)`. More generically: `!within(org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean+)`.

Comment: BTW, it is hard to believe that other than the info messages, you would not have any problems with the proxied filter. In my Spring Boot 2.5.6 example project, proxying a filter derived from `OncePerRequestFilter` kills the whole application during start-up, because the non-proxiable (final) method `GenericFilterBean.init` runs into a `NullPointerException` when trying to access its logger instance field, which of course for a proxy class is not initialised. If you want such a filter proxied, you really have to use JDK proxies, but then are limited to interface methods, like I said.